# Inject Vue component from diet js file

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vite

I have a very simple app vue3:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import './style.css'
import App from './App.vue'

let currentApp = createApp(App);
(window as any).load(currentApp);
currentApp.mount('#app');
```

In the index.html file i import a dist lib:

<script src="http://localhost:5173/dist/assets/index.59eda240.js">

The content of dist JS is:

```
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

(window as any).load = (app: any) => {
    app.component('hello-world', HelloWorld);
}
```

If i use a very simple HelloWorld.vue with just one line of text "Hello", all works fine, but if i put some css classes or more complicated component i obtain:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid VNode type: Symbol() (symbol)    at <HelloWorld>
> at <App>

How can i solve this? Or is there another way to load component at runtime?

Thanks in advance.

P.s. I have no problem doing the same thing with Vue

--------- UPDATE MORE INFO ----------

Vue version

3.2.38

Link to minimal reproduction

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-744fbh?file=src/main.js

Steps to reproduce

The base idea is to have a main app the create a Vue app, and another external lib the load component at runtime.

Open the sample project and show console log to see "Invalid VNode type: Symbol() (symbol)"

What is expected?

I expect to see the components rendered correctly

What is actually happening?

I don't see the component UI, but looking at the console I see the logic code works correctly but we have a warning: Invalid VNode type: Symbol() (symbol) Invalid VNode type: Symbol() (symbol)

System Info

No response

Any additional comments?

This warning appears only in some components, for example, fur a very simple component, it works fine, see here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-nueucw?file=src/App.vue.

You can see the source of helloworld component at the top of lib.js file, inside a comment block

Comment: Use dynamic or asynchronous components for this. I suppose the problem is that `vue` is different in these bundles, this should be avoided. It's unknown what's your case and what's the best way to solve this

Comment: But why just for some components? Why the base component works!?

Comment: Because the components that you use in HelloWorld aren't registered with the same `vue` and cannot be normally resolved from their names. The exact reason can be debugged but it comes from the fact that you have two Vue lib copies in the app. At least this is my understanding of the problem without seeing what really happens. A naive but simple way to avoid this problem is to stick to Vue CDN for all scripts

Comment: But the component has been resolved… the script logic works… I can see the console log output, only the ui is not rendered and only for some components… for some others all works fine… component is mounted correctly, tomorrow I try to make a fiddle

Comment: It's unknown what components we talk about. `Invalid VNode type: Symbol() (symbol) at <HelloWorld>` means that a component failed to resolve inside HelloWorld, more specifically built-in Vue comp - Fragment, Teleport, etc. These comps from one Vue copy won't make sense for another Vue copy. Any way, that's the problem here. You should never have multiple Vue copies on page, unless they are totally different bundled apps, which is not so in your case

Comment: I added two example repos!

Comment: I see, please, add them to the question instead, as they are parts of it

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is that there are multiple Vue library copies per page that interact with each other. This should be avoided, preferably by bundling multiple parts of the application together, so multiple apps would reuse the same modules from  `vendors` chunk. In case this isn't possible or practical, a simple workaround is to use Vue CDN for all applications, either by using `window.Vue` instead of `vue` import, or aliasing the import to global variable by means of a bundler.

The root cause is that Vue built-in element are specific to Vue copy in use - `Fragment`, `Teleport`, `Comment`, etc. They are defined with `Symbol()` to be distinguished from other elements and components and used in compiled component templates. `Symbol` is used in JavaScript to define unique tokens, `Symbol('foo') !== Symbol('foo')`. The symbols of built-in elements from one Vue copy mean nothing to another Vue copy, this is the meaning of this error message.

It can be seen in [this analyzer](https://vue-next-template-explorer.netlify.app/#eyJzcmMiOiIgPGgxIHN0eWxlPVwiYmFja2dyb3VuZC1jb2xvcjpSZWQ7IGZvbnQtc2l6ZTogNDRweDtcIj57eyBtc2cgfX08L2gxPlxyXG48YnV0dG9uIEBjbGljaz1cIm1zZyA9ICdjbGljayc7XCI+Q0xJQ0s8L2J1dHRvbj4iLCJvcHRpb25zIjp7fX0=) that this component template:

```
<h1 style="background-color:Red; font-size: 44px;">{{ msg }}</h1>
<button @click="msg = 'click';">CLICK</button>
```

is compiled to this render function:

```
export function render(_ctx, _cache, $props, $setup, $data, $options) {
  return (_openBlock(), _createElementBlock(_Fragment, null, [
    _createElementVNode("h1", { style: {"background-color":"Red","font-size":"44px"} }, _toDisplayString(_ctx.msg), 1 /* TEXT */),
    _createElementVNode("button", {
      onClick: $event => {_ctx.msg = 'click';}
    }, "CLICK", 8 /* PROPS */, ["onClick"])
  ], 64 /* STABLE_FRAGMENT */))
}
```

Notice that the use of multiple root elements results in wrapping them in `Fragment`, which won't be correctly processed by multiple Vue copies, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Change hello world with another component:

```
<template>
  <div class="relative flex items-top justify-center min-h-screen sm:items-center py-4 sm:pt-0">
    <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">


      <div class="card rounded-lg shadow-lg" style="background-color: yellow;">
        <div class="card-body p-0 m-0 pt-2" style="background-color: orange;">
          <div class="row border-bottom p-0 m-0 pt-2"  style="background-color: brown;">
            <div class="bg-secondary">
              <h5 class="bg-info">test</h5>
              <p>
                test
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div>
              test2
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Only one root element, I have the same issue.